# Good book to learn Server Management Objects (SMO) for C# and SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, smo

Am familiar with TSQL and C#, and would like to read a good book/tutorial on how to use Server Management Objects (SMO) with C# and SQL Server 2008.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not a book per se - but a few good online resources:

- [Getting Started with SMO in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=34)
- [SMO - Manage your SQL Server!](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SMODemo.aspx)
- [SMO Tutorial 1 of n - Programming data storage objects](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SMO_Tutorial_1.aspx?q=sql%20server%20smo)
- [SMO Tutorial 2 of n - (Programming Objects Not Used for Data Storage)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SMO_Tutorial_2.aspx)
- [SMO Tutorial 3 of n - Scripting](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SMO_Tutorial_3.aspx)
- [Getting started with SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1826)

Comment: You've mentioned some great resources.