# Running a Program on Server Memory from Client

Tags: c#, .net, window, client-server

My environment is Windows client server. I have legacy db files sitting on the server that needs to update a new database on the same server. I like a client to be able to run this process. My goal is to minimize network traffic and take advantage of server resources. The client will start the conversion application but the app will run on server memory. After the app is done, the client should receive a call-back of some kind. Is this possible?

I know the client can use Remote Desktop but I was hoping to make the process more seamless.

Thanks,
Wayne

Comment: How about running your application on the client side but let the server do the heavy task? See [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee958158.aspx)

Comment: Cool I'll look into WCF. Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that I think is WCF. But you can directly connect to your Databases with your client and execute the SQL commands with SMO. take a look at [these tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468850/good-book-to-learn-server-management-objects-smo-for-c-sharp-and-sql-server-20)

**Edited:**
WCF is a rapper technology that
covers ASMX web services, .NET remoting, WSE, Enterprise Service, and System.
these previous technologies had got their own pros and cons for example ASMX technology may serve well for the interoperability, but its performance may not be ideal. .NET remoting is a good choice from the performance perspective, but it is not good at interoperability. with coming of WCF you have a technology that covers these all. and it is easier to implement in my opinion.
You can host your service in several ways. 1-Self Hosting. 2-Windows Services Hosting. 3-IIS hosting 4-WAS (windows Activation Service) hosting.

> "WCF 4.0 Multi-tier Services Development with LINQ to Entities"

is a perfect book to getting started with WCF.

Comment: I'm currently looking into .Net Remoting. I'm assuming WCF is a wrapper for remoting and other communication frameworks. Not sure whether or not WCF requires IIS. It appears that .Net remoting is easier to implement but I'm still reading at this point. My destination database for the conversion is db2. Actually it is not a conversion. I'm trying to implement my own database replication run by the client. Because I'm not using SQL Server SMO is not an option.